# In $\frac{\mathbb{C}[t]}{(t^2+1)}$, could $\bar{t}=constant \in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R:=\frac{\mathbb{C}[t]}{(t^2+1)}$.
Let $\bar{t}$ represents the coset in the quotient ring $R$, $\bar{t}:t+(t^2+1)$. Elements of $R$ is polynomial in $\bar{t}$.

If I only consider the element $\bar{t}$, could $\bar{t}=c$ ?where c is a constant in $\mathbb{C}$.
I am not able to show a contradiction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\bar t=t+p(t)(t^2+1)\notin \mathbb C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is impossible. Indeed, If $\overline{t}= \overline{c}$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$, then $t-c\in (t^2+1)$. Hence, there is $p\in \mathbb{C}[t]$ with $t-c = p(t^2+1)$. Clearly $p \ne 0$. Note then that the right hand side has degree $\ge 2$, while the left hand side has degree $1$. Therefore, the equality $t- c = p(t^2+1)$ is impossible, which is the desired contradiction.